# java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.data.count" Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing, junit

**Exception**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.data.count"
        at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:295)
        at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.assertValue(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.lambda$value$2(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:111)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
        at com.amway.elearning.notification.AmwayNotificationElearningApplicationTests.testCountEndPoint(AmwayNotificationElearningApplicationTests.java:267)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: json can not be null or empty
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.Utils.notEmpty(Utils.java:386)
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:342)
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:329)
        at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:292)
        ... 45 more
```

**Code**

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.amway.elearning.notification.controller.InAppNotificationController;
import com.amway.elearning.notification.model.response.CountVO;
import com.amway.elearning.notification.repository.InAppNotificationRepository;
import com.amway.elearning.notification.service.InAppNotificationService;
import com.amway.elearning.notification.service.impl.InAppNotificationServiceImpl;
import com.amway.elearning.notification.util.TracerUtil;


@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {})
@TestPropertySource(locations = { "classpath:application-messages.properties", "classpath:application.properties",
                                  "classpath:application-sonar-project.properties" })
public class AmwayNotificationElearningApplicationTests {

  
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AmwayNotificationElearningApplicationTests.class);
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private InAppNotificationRepository inAppNotificationRepository;

    @Mock
    TracerUtil<CountVO> countNotificationUtil;
    
    private InAppNotificationService inAppNotificationService; 

    private InAppNotificationController inAppNotificationController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       inAppNotificationController = new InAppNotificationController();
        inAppNotificationService = new InAppNotificationServiceImpl(inAppNotificationRepository);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(inAppNotificationController, "inAppNotificationService", inAppNotificationService);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(inAppNotificationController, "countNotificationUtil", countNotificationUtil);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(inAppNotificationService, "inAppNotificationRepository", inAppNotificationRepository);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(inAppNotificationController).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testCountEndPoint() throws Exception {
      when(inAppNotificationRepository.countByUserIdAndIsReadFalse("100")).thenReturn(5L);
    
      MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/{userId}/notifications/count",100))
         
          .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
          .andExpect(jsonPath("$.data.count").value(5L))
          .andReturn();
    }
```

**Logs**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/user/100/notifications/count
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.amway.elearning.notification.controller.InAppNotificationController
           Method = com.amway.elearning.notification.controller.InAppNotificationController#getCount(String)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not returning json from `get` operation.

Can you use `accept` method & see if your test able to evaluate jsonpath?

```
MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/{userId}/notifications/count",100))
             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).... //call other methods
```